# Coundown Timer Inside ForEach Loop Php

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, countdowntimer

I am trying to Show a Countdown Timer Inside Foreach loop for every record in PHP Codeigniter Framework, It is basically showing Datediff between current date and mysql database date value as how many days left, Below is my code.Problem is it is showing countdown timer for single record only not for every record i need

```
 <?php foreach ($my_courses as $my_course):
     $course_details = $this->crud_model->get_course_by_id($my_course['course_id'])->row_array();
 
     <!-- countdown timer-->
                             
     <?php if ($course_details['is_onlineclass']==='Yes'): ?>
     <span style="display:inline-block;font-size:12px;font-color:crimson;"><?php 
     $t=$course_details['live_class_schedule_time'];
                                   
     //time difference in seconds for coundown timer
     $date = new DateTime();
     $date2 = new DateTime(date("yy-m-d h:i:s a", $t));  
     $diff = $date->getTimestamp() - $date2->getTimestamp() ;
     echo $diff;                                      
     ?></span>
                                  
     <span  id="<?echo $my_course['course_id']?>" class="timer" style="font-size:smaller;color:crimson;"></span>                                     
     <?php endif; ?>
                                 
     <script>
         var initialTime = <?echo $diff?>;

         var seconds = initialTime;
         function timer() {
         var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
         var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
         var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
         var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
         var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
         var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
         if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
         remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
         }
         document.getElementById('<?echo $my_course['course_id']?>').innerHTML = days + "days " + hours + "hours " + minutes + "min " + remainingSeconds+ "sec left";
         if (seconds == 0) {
              learInterval(countdownTimer);
              document.getElementById('<?echo $my_course['course_id']?>').innerHTML = "Completed";
         } else {
           seconds--;
                }
         }
            var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer()', 1000);
                                      
         </script>
```

What is the wrong I am doing and How to show the timer for every record

Comment: Are you sure the `foreach loop` is working fine? Your countdown script is fine

Comment: for others record it is showing fine but echo $diff;   and countdown timer is showing only for single record

Comment: can you paste the html output of the above loop?

Comment: I have changed the timer id to  id="<?echo $my_course['course_id']?>" and now its html output is <span id="2" class="timer" style="font-size:smaller;color:crimson;">1days 4hours 57min 10sec left</span> getting only one course id

Comment: The way you are doing it is very rudimentary and it generates a lot of extra HTML and js code. but still, I have posted an answer for the way you are writing the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function name and call should also be unique.

**EDIT**

Also you messed up a log of code.  I have commented the `foreach loop` and put my own `for loop`. Modify accordingly

Try this.

```
<?php 


$my_course['course_id'] = 0;

for($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++):
// foreach ($my_courses as $my_course):
// $course_details = $this->crud_model->get_course_by_id($my_course['course_id'])->row_array();

// You need to comment this out when you put your code live
$course_details['is_onlineclass'] = "Yes"; 
$course_details['live_class_schedule_time'] = time() + rand(0, 300); 
$my_course['course_id'] += 1;
// remove till here

if ($course_details['is_onlineclass']==='Yes'):
?>
    <span style="display:inline-block;font-size:12px;font-color:crimson;">
    <?php 
        $t=$course_details['live_class_schedule_time'];
                                    
        //time difference in seconds for coundown timer
        $date = new DateTime();
        $date2 = new DateTime(date("yy-m-d h:i:s a", $t));  
        $diff = $date->getTimestamp() - $date2->getTimestamp() ;
    ?>
    </span>
                                
    <span  id="<?php echo $my_course['course_id']; ?>" class="timer" style="font-size:smaller;color:crimson;"></span>                                     
<?php endif; ?>
                            
<script>
    var initialTime = <?php echo $diff; ?>

    var seconds = initialTime;
    function timer<?php echo $my_course['course_id'];?>() {
        var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
        var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
        var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
        var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
        var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
        var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
        if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
        }
        document.getElementById('<?php echo $my_course['course_id']?>').innerHTML = days + "days " + hours + "hours " + minutes + "min " + remainingSeconds+ "sec left";
        if (seconds == 0) {
            learInterval(countdownTimer);
            document.getElementById('<?php echo $my_course['course_id']?>').innerHTML = "Completed";
        } else {
            seconds--;
        }
    }
    var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer<?php echo $my_course["course_id"];?>()', 1000);
                                
    </script>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

**EDIT: Here is your code**

```
<?php 

foreach ($my_courses as $my_course):
$course_details = $this->crud_model->get_course_by_id($my_course['course_id'])->row_array();


if ($course_details['is_onlineclass']==='Yes'):
?>
    <span style="display:inline-block;font-size:12px;font-color:crimson;">
    <?php 
        $t=$course_details['live_class_schedule_time'];
                                    
        //time difference in seconds for coundown timer
        $date = new DateTime();
        $date2 = new DateTime(date("yy-m-d h:i:s a", $t));  
        $diff = $date->getTimestamp() - $date2->getTimestamp() ;
    ?>
    </span>
                                
    <span  id="<?php echo $my_course['course_id']; ?>" class="timer" style="font-size:smaller;color:crimson;"></span>                                     
<?php endif; ?>
                            
<script>
    var initialTime = <?php echo $diff; ?>

    var seconds = initialTime;
    function timer<?php echo $my_course['course_id'];?>() {
        var days        = Math.floor(seconds/24/60/60);
        var hoursLeft   = Math.floor((seconds) - (days*86400));
        var hours       = Math.floor(hoursLeft/3600);
        var minutesLeft = Math.floor((hoursLeft) - (hours*3600));
        var minutes     = Math.floor(minutesLeft/60);
        var remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;
        if (remainingSeconds < 10) {
        remainingSeconds = "0" + remainingSeconds; 
        }
        document.getElementById('<?php echo $my_course['course_id']?>').innerHTML = days + "days " + hours + "hours " + minutes + "min " + remainingSeconds+ "sec left";
        if (seconds == 0) {
            learInterval(countdownTimer);
            document.getElementById('<?php echo $my_course['course_id']?>').innerHTML = "Completed";
        } else {
            seconds--;
        }
    }
    var countdownTimer = setInterval('timer<?php echo $my_course["course_id"];?>()', 1000);
                                
    </script>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Check now. You messed up a lot. I have commented the `foreach loop` and put my own `for loop`. Modify accordingly

Comment: tried now showing two timer in same record not in every record see image pls https://imgur.com/xJrEtMW

Comment: ok after I commented out this // You need to comment this out when you put your code live
$course_details['is_onlineclass'] = "Yes"; 
$course_details['live_class_schedule_time'] = time() + rand(0, 300); 
$my_course['course_id'] += 1;
// remove till here  it is showing timer in first record only

Comment: I commented out below  and then revert the id to countdown but showing only for first record now  // You need to comment this out when you put your code live
$course_details['is_onlineclass'] = "Yes"; 
$course_details['live_class_schedule_time'] = time() + rand(0, 300); 
$my_course['course_id'] += 1;
// remove till here

Comment: @Mithu. You look into `id="countdown"`, I believe. It must be from the CSS. But, I cannot predict the design with limited knowledge about your code.  Check your CSS as already the timer is showing inside your `foreach loop`

Comment: may be span id is not generating for the all course id

Comment: another thing with this  $my_course['course_id'] = 0;for($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++):  it shows timer for first record but if i omit then it shows timer for second record

Comment: @Mithu, yes, of course, you have to delete that. That is why I have updated my answer and put your new code as well. So that you know what to keep and what to delete

Comment: no only for one record i think it is problem with span id not creating  foreach record it is only creating once

Comment: Yes please check your CSS and divs. I am sure, it the problem with your CSS and HTML code placement

Comment: this is showing time difference for every record <?php if ($course_details['is_onlineclass']==='Yes'): $t=$course_details['live_class_schedule_time'];  
 if(!empty($t)){$date = new DateTime();$date2 = new DateTime(date("yy-m-d h:i:s a", $t)); $diff = $date->getTimestamp() - $date2->getTimestamp() ;echo $diff;}?> <?php endif; ?> <span  id="<?echo $course_details['id']?>" class="timer" style="font-size:smaller;color:crimson;"></span>
                                     `

Comment: look <span id="<?echo $course_details['id']?>" class="timer" style="font-size:smaller;color:crimson;"></span>  is outside of <?php endif; ?> can i put this inside <?php endif; ?>

Comment: echo $diff; is outputting difference for every record

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219941/discussion-between-chilarai-and-mithu).